# display the first 200 Prime numbers in Java

Tags: java

Hi there i'm having some trouble with java and letting it display the first 200 Prime numbers.
What i have now is a code that has a limit of 200 numbers and it will pick the prime numbers out of the 200 numbers.
But what if i want to exactly display 200 prime numbers?

I have a code that has 2 methods in it. 1st method focusses on displaying the numbers and the 2nd method focusses on determing if the number is a prime number or not.
if it's true it will return it to method 1.

So what i was trying to do is make an counter and a while loop in a for loop.
Only it resulted in only giving 1 certain number 200 times so i used the commentary // to block the while code.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    int limit = 200;
    for (int getal =2; getal<=limit; getal++)
    {
    //int count = 0;
    //while (count < 201)

        if (Priem(getal))
        {
            //count++;
            System.out.println(getal);
        }
    }

}   

public static boolean Priem (int getal)
{

    for (int i=2; i<getal; i++)
    {

        if (getal%i == 0)
        {
        return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Anyone got any ideas how to pull this off? thanks for the help!

Comment: Your code currently looks at all numbers up to 200 and checks if they are prime.

Comment: Please use [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). Straying from the accepted standard makes your come **much** harder to read. For example, method names should be lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

int countofPrime = 0;
for (int getal =2; ; getal++)
{
//int count = 0;
//while (count < 201)

    if (Priem(getal))
    {
        countofPrime++;
        System.out.println(getal);
        if(countofPrime == 200)
            break;
    }
}

}   

public static boolean Priem (int getal)
{

for (int i=2; i<getal; i++)
{

    if (getal%i == 0)
    {
    return false;
    }

}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Ah cool thanks for the solution! works perfectly!
i didn't knew you could break the condition in the for loop anyway thank for the quick reply!

Comment: @SteelDevil please accept the answer it if answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm. this is good method to display as many prime numbers as you want.